# XMPPFramework : can I determine the online/offline status of a user at all?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xmpp, xmppframework

How would I determine if a user is online/offline using XMPPFramework for iPhone?

I have their JID etc etc. Is there a way of requesting a presence or something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked out the source code of the XMPPFramework sample project?

If I remember correctly, this should be the relevant code snippet:

```
// Subscribe to the buddy's presence
// 
// <presence to="bareJID" type="subscribe"/>

NSXMLElement *presence = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"presence"];
[presence addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[jid bare]];
[presence addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"subscribe"];

[xmppStream sendElement:presence];
```

And the callback your stream delegate gets should be

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence;
```

I assume that you already have the xmmpframework source, if not, you can clone the repository here

```
hg clone https://xmppframework.googlecode.com/hg/ xmppframework
```

The sample projects are in the "Xcode" folder.

Comment: That would essentially mean you would first need to get the roster then make the individual calls

Comment: @puzzle hey can you give some more idea how to find particular user status online/offline ?

Comment: @puzzle give some more idea to get user status

Comment: @Bucket What exactly is not working? This answer is almost 7 years old, XMPPFramework has changed quite a bit since (also Google Code is dead, so you'll find the framework on GitHub instead). One thing hasn't changed though: You'll want to look at the example code in the Xcode folder! I'd suggest you search there for `xmppRosterDidChange`.

Comment: @puzzle : Thanks for your reply, i have done with  this issue yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

First, Both side subscription in ROSTER List is must required for getting user status.

[image]

Here, How to subscribe & Accept a Presence Request.

```
    let senderName = strReceiverEjabberedName + "@" + eJabVirtualHost
    let roomJID = XMPPJID(string: senderName)
    
    // Send subscribe request
    let detxTag:XMLElement = XMLElement(name: "presence")
    detxTag.addAttribute(withName: "to", stringValue: roomJID?.bare ?? "")
    detxTag.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "subscribe")
    xmppController.xmppStream.send(detxTag)
    
    // Send subscribed request
    let detxTaged:XMLElement = XMLElement(name: "presence")
    detxTaged.addAttribute(withName: "to", stringValue: roomJID?.bare ?? "")
    detxTaged.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "subscribed")
    xmppController.xmppStream.send(detxTaged)
    
    // Subscribe & Accept Presence Request
    xmppController.xmppRoster?.subscribePresence(toUser: roomJID!)
    xmppController.xmppRoster?.acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequest(from: roomJID!, andAddToRoster: true)
```

If your friend send precense request to you then you received request in Roster Delegate.

```
extension XMPPServiceController: XMPPRosterDelegate {
    func xmppRoster(_ sender: XMPPRoster, didReceivePresenceSubscriptionRequest presence: XMPPPresence) {
        sender.acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequest(from: presence.from!, andAddToRoster: true)
    }
}
```

Once the above steps did you will receive your friend Online/Offline Status in the below XMPP delegate method.

```
func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream?, didReceivePresence presence: XMPPPresence?) {
    let presenceType = presence?.type
    if presenceType == "available" { //ONLINE }
    else if presenceType == "unavailable" { //OFFLINE }
}
```