# ios - should the user added in the XMPP roster to start messaging?

Tags: ios, database, xmpp

is the user should be existing in the roster to be able to message with that user using XMPP in iOS? if then is it possible to use XMPP without a roster? (to send and receive messages with any random users)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible to send XMPP messages to any user without roster, you only need to have other user's JID.

xmpp clients won't let you send direct messages due to spam protection policy, but if your app is used on both sides than this can be easily achieved!

Comment: Thank you. One more question about this. If I have the JID of the other person but the JID is not in the roster, is there any way to check if the person is online at the moment or not?

Comment: yes this should also be quite possible, refer [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960037/xmppframework-can-i-determine-the-online-offline-status-of-a-user-at-all) for details

Comment: In general, no.  You must subscribe to their presence first, which implicitly puts them on your roster.